# Redis Security: Remote Connection to Redis Server Binded to Localhost

Tags: security, redis

I have a security requirement to bind my redis-server to localhost in the redis.conf file.

However, I also need to make remote connections to the redis-server. May I check what is the best way to establish such remote connections while binding the server to its localhost?

Comment: AFAIK, if you bind Redis to the local host, you cannot connect to Redis from a remote client. Instead, you should configure Redis with a password, and let remote client connect to it with the password.

Comment: @for_stack thanks for the input, however, my company is enforcing us to both bind locally and enforce a password, but remote connections are needed....
However, i saw this: https://redislabs.com/blog/stunnel-secure-redis-ssl/, not sure if stunnel works for anyone.